# Which SAPUI5 control can be used to display dynamic content in form of Labels or lists?

Tags: sapui5

I am developing a Online Questionnaire application. In this I am using Checkbox and Labels inside a VBox and Hbox control to display the options for my answers. These answer options I am getting them from my questionnaire.json model.

Following is my **App.view.xml** showing the answers layout:

```
<VBox id="multipleChoices">
                                <items>
                                    <HBox backgroundDesign="Solid" alignItems="Center">
                                        <items>
                                            <CheckBox id="mCheckBox0"/>
                                            <Label text="" id="multipleChoice0" width="500px"/>
                                            <CheckBox id="mCheckBox1"/>
                                            <Label text="" id="multipleChoice1" width="500px"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </HBox>
                                    <HBox backgroundDesign="Solid" alignItems="Center">
                                        <items>
                                            <CheckBox id="mCheckBox2"/>
                                            <Label text="" id="multipleChoice2" width="500px"/>
                                            <CheckBox id="mCheckBox3"/>
                                            <Label text="" id="multipleChoice3" width="500px"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </HBox>
                                </items>
                            </VBox>
```

It gets applied in front end as follows:

**Q1.png** [image: First Question]

**Q2.png** [image: Second Question]

**Problem:**
You can see in Q2.png 4 Labels and 4 radio buttons are being displayed even though there are only two answer options. How do I achieve the scenario where the labels's and radio buttons/ check boxes appear in same number as the answer choices and extra ones are hidden?
Is there a dynamic control which can help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

you should bind your question from your model to a List and a ListItem can have a template with Labels and checkboxs, so you don't need to care about the size of your answers. The way you are doing it at the moment is way too static.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the below control:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputListItem/preview

InputListItem ?

Comment: Yes for example `<InputListItem label="High Performance">
   <RadioButton
    groupName="GroupInputListItem"
    selected="true" />
  </InputListItem>` would fit the most. You need to bind the answers to the List control by filling the aggregation "items"

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox has a **text** property, therefore you could remove the labels and do a binding inside that property

```
<CheckBox id="mCheckBox1" text="{model/textOption1}"/>
<CheckBox id="mCheckBox2" text="{model/textOption1}"/>
```